# Gmail unread count not visible for long labels

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

In Gmail, labels with long names has their count cut off. Ex:

[image: screen snippet of a long Gmail label where the message count isn't visible]

I've been shortening label names, but shortening names is not an elegant solution, IMHO.

I would like either:

1. Names would be auto trimmed:   Platform-u...(50)

or maybe

2. When hovering over label, unread count shown in tooltip.

etc.

Is there any way at all to find out the unread count with long label names at the moment?